# passing a javascript array to rails controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to use jquery selectable to replace my ugly checkboxes. I added this code to my form_for, but i don't know how to pass the tag_list array back to my controller.

```
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />

    <style>
    #feedback { font-size: 1.4em; }
    #selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
    #selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
    #selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
    #selectable li { margin: 3px; padding: 0.4em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
    </style>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#selectable" ).selectable({
            stop: function() {
                var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();
                var tag_names = []
                $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
                    var item = this.innerHTML;
                    result.append( ( item ) );
                    tag_names.push( item )
                });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="feedback">
<span>Tags:</span> <span id="select-result">none</span>.
</p>

<ol id="selectable">
    <%@tags.each_key do |tag| %>
        <li class="ui-widget-content"> #<%=tag%> </li>
    <%end%>
</ol>
```

Comment: If you find my answer useful, please upvote it and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways i can see:

1. First, create a hidden field in the form. And populate its value with the `tag_names` through Jquery. It will automatically get submit during form submit.
2. Secondly, you can create a GLOBAL JS variable `tag_names`. It will be populated as above and then override the form submit action in Jquery to include `tag_names`. Like this :

   ```
   $("#myForm").submit(function() {
        $(this).append("<input type='hidden' name='tag_names' 
        value='"+tag_names+"' />");
        $(this).submit();
   })
   ```